# ListView not populating

Tags: android, data-binding, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

In my app I mention the origin and destination and the app would give me a list of buses. 
I have a text field and a `Button` in `firstActivity` and when I click the `Button` a list of possible places(which is another activity that has a `ListView`) would come for selecting the origin.

The thing is I'm able to move from `firstActivity` to the `secondActivity` but I'm not able to see the `ListView` at all. I created a separate array of places in an xml file, gave it an `id` and called it out while creating the `ArrayAdapter`.

The `secondActivity`:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> placesAdapter= new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,R.array.fromArray);
System.out.println("SSSSSSSSSSSSSSS"+placesAdapter);
ListView placesView= (ListView)this.findViewById(R.id.mylist);
placesView.setAdapter(placesAdapter);
placesView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an `ArrayAdapter` from an array then use this method:

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> placesAdapter= ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.fromArray, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help ! can u tell me why the other one wouldnt work?

Comment: @user1261376 The version that you used takes a context, a layout file for the row(`android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`) and the last `int` should be the id of a `TextView` from that layout(but you provided the id of an array so this wouldn't have worked) where the adapter will put the data. This adapter doesn't have any elements in it so the list is empty and doesn't show any rows.